# what's the difference between the following x86 code

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64, calling-convention

I have the following C code:

```
void foo(int *p){
    *p = 5;
}
void test(){
    int p = 0;
    foo (&p);
}
```

However, I have a question about the x86 instruction. For the foo function, should

```
*p = 5
```

corresponds to

```
movq $0x5, (%rdi)
```

Comment: In the [AMD64 System V ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) (which appears to be the case here from the generated instruction) RDI is the register where the first parameter to a function is passed. RDI contains a pointer to `p` (a 32-bit integer). `movq $0x5, (%rdi)` would move the value 5 to the 64-bit (long) pointed to by the address RDI. I doubt this is the generated code. I would expect `movl $0x5, (%rdi)` since `p` is a pointer to a 32-bit integer

Comment: thank you. Could you also please explain is p stored in memory (data segment) or memory (stack)?

Comment: Assuming optimizations don't eliminate the variable altogether `int p = 0;` inside a function would place `p` in local (automatic) variable storage and in most compilers including GCC that would be on the stack.

Comment: `int p` is in stack memory because it has automatic storage and its address is taken.  It can only be eliminated if `foo` inlines.  `int *p` is also automatic storage, but is only used inside `foo`, so can stay in RDI even without function inlining.  Wasn't clear which `p` you were talking about, and you have 2 variables with the same name.

Comment: You have two `p`s.  That makes asking questions about where `p` is stored somewhat ambiguous.  The first `p` is most likely stored in memory in the stack region, because it is a local variable and the C code asks for its address, which implies memory.  The second `p` is stored in the argument register `%rdi` as a formal parameter, though could be moved elsewhere upon entry.  The question would be more clear if one of the `p`s was renamed, maybe to `q`?